# print all the titles of a content type

Tags: drupal, drupal-7

I created a content type: "period" Then, I created instances of this content type. Now I would like, on a page. Tpl.php put the instructions, to make all the titles of the instances that I put on this content type. is it possible?

Answer (score 1):

There are a lot of different ways to achieve this.

**The Drupal Way - Views**

As you have a content type you can create a view. It's a bit complex to get started with but once you grasp the concept it is the best way of creating lists. This does not lead to a .tpl.php file however.
http://drupal.org/project/views

**Custom module**

You can create a menu entry with a page. Then you would want to use db_query or other parts of the DB API to get the instances and then you could implement a template for it yourself.

It would be a rather long example so I'll refer you to the module development docs: http://drupal.org/node/361112

I hope these were helpful. Your problem is pretty wide.